# How to just print numpy 2d array in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm new in Python 3.

My code is following, and I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
test = np.random.randn(10)
print (test)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

(+)
I already imported numpy, and detailed error msg is following.

```
    TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3e506a0fbc4a> in <module>()
      1 test=np.random.randn(10)
----> 2 print(test)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in array_str(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small)
   1937 
   1938     """
-> 1939     return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "", str)
   1940 
   1941 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    386             repr_running.add(key)
    387             try:
--> 388                 return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    389             finally:
    390                 repr_running.discard(key)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py in array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, separator, prefix, style, formatter)
    521     else:
    522         lst = _array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small,
--> 523                             separator, prefix, formatter=formatter)
    524     return lst
    525 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py in _array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, separator, prefix, formatter)
    344                   prefix="", formatter=None):
    345 
--> 346     if a.size > _summaryThreshold:
    347         summary_insert = "..., "
    348         data = _leading_trailing(a)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: The code you show runs fine.  Are you sure that's what's producing that error?  I don't see any connection.

Comment: That helps.  Have you changed the numpy print options?  It looks like threshold is a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 it was decided to be more strict when comparing elements. Therefore, the comparison between 'int' and 'str' will raise an error (this error is difficult to reproduce). 
There are many ways to fix this, one option I have used is the `.tolist()` method in numpy.

```
import numpy as np
test = np.random.randn(10)
print(test.tolist())
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks Like you haven't included the `import` function.

Try this out:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.random.randn(10)
print (test)
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score -2):

Change the print option will make this array go away.Looks like u have changed the
default threshold setting in numpy.

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=5)
```